# Dropbox menu is not closing on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi my full code is in jsfidlle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h4TMu/1/), i want when i will mouseover or click in "giris" my div to be appear in mouseout to dissappear , how can i do it ?

My Code :

```
<div class="sign_in_holder">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="option_content tab-pane tcell-login-box active" embeddedlogin="true" id="trk-sign_in">
            <form id="user_sign_in" class="sign_in js-do_login">
                <ol class="steps clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" class="text input_restrict_decimal tcell-user" maxlength="11" placeholder="GSM Numaranız" title="GSM Numaranız">
                    </li>
                    <li class="password">
                        <input type="password" class="text tcell-password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Turkcell Şifreniz" title="Turkcell Şifreniz">
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <button type="button" id="signin_button" class="btn button-cta tcell-submit-btn">GİRİŞ YAP</button>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="dropbox_position_element carrot_up"></span></div>
<span class="dropbox_position_element carrot_up"></span></div></li>
```

Check This [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h4TMu/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6XDBE/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a css only solution you can use this code:
Ankit demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6XDBE/7/
your demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/h4TMu/5/

```
 .nav-actions:hover .dropbox{
   display: block!important;
 }
 .dropbox:hover{
   display: block!important;
 }
```

you can see the edit at the end of the css, the important is caused by the inline dysplay:none

but in this case you need to use the parent (container) so you need to take in consideration the dimension of it.